# Is $\Pi_{I} \mathbb{Z}$ a principal ideal ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Why is $\Pi_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$ a <s>PID</s> principal ideal ring? (Edit: the OP later revealed that they had not meant to include "domain." Edited to reflect that.)

Actually, I saw this statement for $i \in I$ where $I$ is an indexing set so I'm uncertain the conditions on $I$. Is it true for $I$ where $I$ is countably infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doubly not a PID.

The *infinite* product is not even Noetherian, so it can't be a principal ideal ring.

Furthermore, the product of any two nonzero rings is *never* a domain, so it's definitely not a domain.

Suggested exercise: prove both these observations for yourself! If you need a hint on the first claim, notice that $\oplus_{i=1}^\infty\Bbb Z$ is a proper ideal of the ring you mention. Try to see why it can't be generated by a single element.

Comment: Oh I apologize, you're right the claim was not that the product was a PID, rather the claim is that every ideal of the product is principal. I suppose I will edit the question.

Comment: Dear @Camilo : When someone supplies an answer to a question in a certain form, changing the question by a lot is discouraged because it confuses later readers when they see the question and answers. It's perfectly fine to add a note at the end of the post explaining what you meant, though. I stuck in an explanatory note for you. Please remember this in the future.